# How can we add dropdown like feature in typehead angular bootstrap

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using an angular UI typeahead from [Angular bootstrap UI](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home)

I would like to add a dropdown icon in typehead input and on click of that icon all the options should be visible.

Even if I select one option when I click on the dropdown icon all options should be visible how can i implement this?

```
<input
  type="text"
  ng-model="search"
  placeholder="Search"
  uib-typeahead="eachCatigory in catigories | limitTo:8"/>
```

Any suggestions are great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by the [open on focus example](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#focus) in Angular Powered Bootstrap.
Write your own button icon and run click$.next('') to pass an empty searchterm to the input. Wich will then toggle open all the results.

I just forked the open on focus example and added the button icon and the toggle method.

In  your template:

```
<div class="input-container">
    <button (click)="toggle()"><img src="image_src_here" alt="Icon"></button>
    <input
    id="typeahead-focus"
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    [(ngModel)]="model"
    [ngbTypeahead]="search"
    #instance="ngbTypeahead"
/>
</div>
```

In your component style:

```
.input-container button {
  position: absolute;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: .35rem;
}
.input-container input {
  padding-left: 2rem;
}
```

In your component:

```
export class NgbdTypeaheadFocus {
  model: any;
  showAll = false;
  @ViewChild('instance', { static: true }) instance: NgbTypeahead;
  focus$ = new Subject<string>();
  click$ = new Subject<string>();

  toggle() {
    this.click$.next('');
  }

  search: OperatorFunction<string, readonly string[]> = (
    text$: Observable<string>
  ) => {
    const debouncedText$ = text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged()
    );
    const clicksWithClosedPopup$ = this.click$.pipe(
      filter(() => !this.instance.isPopupOpen())
    );
    const inputFocus$ = this.focus$;

    return merge(debouncedText$, inputFocus$, clicksWithClosedPopup$).pipe(
      map((term) =>
        (term === ''
          ? states
          : states.filter(
              (v) => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1
            )
        ).slice(0, 10)
      )
    );
  };
}
```

Here is my [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r9rdqj?file=src/main.ts)

Comment: how can we do this toggle in angular-js pls help me

Comment: Sorry but the question was tagged by angular and not AngularJS before you changed it. So I have posted my workaround for angular. I am not familiar with AngularJS. I have tried to find a workaround for it too but it did not work the  same way in AngularJS.

Comment: If this answer is not helpful I would just delete it